# When GBM model saved and loaded doesn't give same predicted values when model loaded again and again

Tags: r, gbm

I trained a GBM model (classification) and saved it using:

```
saveRDS(gbmfit, file='E:/..../gbm_nb.rds')
```

when I am using above model for scoring data, I load it using:

```
gbmfit <- readRDS('E:/..../gbm_nb.rds')
```

and predict:

```
nb_lapse$PRED <- predict(gbmfit, nb_lapse, type='response', n.trees=2000)
```

This PRED values should be same each time I run it against same scoring data. But some of these values come different. I have printed these by two runs of above code and the differences are around 3% of records. The difference I have printed as such:
[image]

Where ID is the unique number. PRD_ORIG is coming in the first run and PRED_NEW is coming in the second run. In second run I am loading model again. If I am not loading model, instead score data again on already loaded model then I don't see any difference in PRED values.

Have you seen this kind of behavior? I was expecting that this should give same PRED values, for same scoring data, each time I will load model and score it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I have one categorical variable, say A, with many categories. In the train data, I have capped those categories based on another variable, say B, in the data frame. In scoring data frame that variable B is not present. Therefore, despite my scoring data goes through capping code, actual capping of categories doesn't happen. R doesn't throw any error if code is not executed. Therefore in scoring data I end up having more categories in categorical variable A than in train data on which model was trained. This was creating problem and I was getting different predicted values for those data points where categories were different, or not present, than in train data. Once I capped scoring data categorical variable as in train data my predicted values are coming same every time.